# How can i display time minus 6 hours

Tags: date-time, timestamp

how can i display date and time minus six hours in a post. For example now it's 23/02/2016 14:54, I need to display 23/02/2016 8:54.
I'm using this in function.php of my theme:

```
function displaydate(){
    return date('d/m/Y G:i');
}
add_shortcode('date', 'displaydate');
```

and then I add [date] in post, but how can I display six hours back?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd recommend prefixing your shortcode, as date is a very generic name, and is likely to clash. Also, if your -6 hours is to adjust to your timezone, there are better ways of doing this using WordPress APIs rather than hardcoding the difference

Answer (score 4):

This is not a WordPress question, but to help you out:

```
function displaydate() {
    return date( 'd/m/Y G:i', strtotime( '-6 hours' ) );
}
add_shortcode('date', 'displaydate');
```

The shortcode itself should work fine.

Comment: Thanks fischi, it works fine. Now I have this code in my archive.php: <?php echo date_i18n('d/m/Y H:m', time()); ?>, how can I obtain same effect (six hours back)?

Comment: just replace `time()` with `strtotime( '-6 hours' )`

Comment: Mightn't it also be useful to include a call to date_default_timezone_set? Otherwise, if/when you move the site to a server in a different timezone, you might not be getting the result you want.